# raspberry pi, apt-get update in script does not work

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

from the command line, it works.

If I put the same line a script file maintain.script:

```
echo UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – UPDATE
sudo apt-get update
echo UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – UPGRADE
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and run:

```
sudo ./maintain.sh
```

I get errors:

```
E: Invalid operation update
E: Invalid operation upgrade
```

I have marked the script as an executable.

**Updated After Comment from FSQ**

Here is the script file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – UPDATE"
apt-get update
echo "UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – UPGRADE"
apt-get upgrade
echo "UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – DISTRIBUTION"
apt-get dist-upgrade
echo "REMOVING APPLICATION ORPHANS"
apt-get autoremove –purge
echo "UPDATING FIRMWARE"
rpi-update
```

Here is the command:

```
pi@raspberrypi2 ~/projects $ sudo ./maintain.sh
```

Here is the result:

```
: not foundsh: 1: ./maintain.sh: #!/bin/bash
UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – UPDATE
E: Invalid operation update
UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – UPGRADE
E: Invalid operation upgrade
UPDATING SYSTEM SOFTWARE – DISTRIBUTION
E: Invalid operation dist-upgrade
REMOVING APPLICATION ORPHANS
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package –purge
UPDATING FIRMWARE
: not foundsh: 11: ./maintain.sh: rpi-update
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a file format problem.  I was editing the files over a folder share using Windows notepad, which uses a different \r\n to Linux.

Here is the command that corrected my script file:

```
sed -i 's/\r//' maintain.sh
```

Here is a script file I use to do all the script files in a folder, and make sure they are executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Correcting script file formats"
for file in *.sh
do
    echo $file
    sed -i 's/\r//' $file
    chmod +x $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the start of your script? `#!/bin/bash`

This is how it would work on ubuntu not sure about raspbian